# Filling a textbox with some text by checking an html checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How I can do this...
I want fill a *textbox* with this "**9:00 AM - 2:00 PM**" when I check the '**morning**' checkbox,
and "**2:00 PM - 7:00 PM**" when I check the '**evening**' checkbox, **BUT** when I check those two checkboxes
the *textbox* filled with this text "**9:00 AM - 7:00 PM**" otherwise make a textbox with no text.

I try some way but not work, this is my **HTML** markup code

```
              <!-- Morning -->
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="input-group mb-4 input-group-lg">
                    <div class="inputGroup">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text"><img src="icon/morningIcon.png" class="pl-1" alt="icon"></span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="morning" name="working"/>
                      <label for="morning" id="morningClick" onclick="shifting()">Morning</label>
                    </div>
                </div>           
              </div>

              <!-- Evening -->
              <div class="col-6">
                <div class="input-group mb-4 input-group-lg">
                  <div class="inputGroup">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><img src="icon/moonIcon.png" class="pl-1" alt="icon"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="evening" name="working"/>
                    <label for="evening" id="eveningClick" onclick="shifting()">Evening</label>
                  </div>
                </div>             
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- timing in shift -->
            <div class="input-group mb-4 input-group-lg">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><img src="icon/clockIcon.png" class="pl-1" alt="icon"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clock_field" id="clock-field" placeholder="Timing in Work" disabled="disabled"/>
            </div>
```

And this is **JS** code

```
function shifting() {
var morning = document.getElementById("morning");
var evening = document.getElementById("evening");
var working = document.getElementById("clock-field");

// If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
// morning
if (morning.checked == true){
    working.value = "9:00AM - 2:00PM";
}
if (morning.checked == false){
    working.value = null;
}

//evening
if (evening.checked == true){
    working.value = "2:00PM - 7:00PM";
}
if (evening.checked == false){
    working.value = null;
}

//morning and evening
if (morning.checked == true && evening.checked == true){
    working.value = "9:00AM - 7:00PM";
}
if (morning.checked == false && evening.checked == false){
    working.value = null;
}
```

}

**My form is this**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdmvy.png)

Comment: Why not just use a 24 hour time picker and avoid the problem entirely, and make the UI easier for your users? If you'd like more specific help please edit the question to include the code you've written in an attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: I agree with Rory, if you still need it as you listed above then let us know.

Comment: ...and show your code, please.

Comment: Your question lacks any sort of real data with which other users can attempt to assist you. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question, providing more information.

Comment: thanks to all, this is my code JS and HTML

Comment: You seem to be using native js and not jquery?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should get you started (though has obvious problems)

```
<input type="text" id="output" />

<div>
  <input type="radio" onclick="selectTimeOfDay('morning')" value="Morning" />
  <span>Morning</span><br />
  <input type="radio" onclick="selectTimeOfDay('evening')" value="Evening" />
  <span>Evening</span>
</div>
```

And the Javascript

```
const morningTimeString = "9:00 AM - 2:00 PM";
const eveningTimeString = "2:00 PM - 7:00 PM";

const output = document.getElementById("output");
function selectTimeOfDay(t) {
    if (t === "morning") {
    output.value = morningTimeString;
  }
  else if (t === "evening") {
    output.value = eveningTimeString;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phk5rq7c/

Comment: What about the third case?

Comment: If those two checkboxes is checked?

Comment: You check a datatype not checked HTML checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Not a very optimized code, but this should work for you:

```js
const mng = "9:00 AM - 2:00 PM";
const eve = "2:00 PM - 7:00 PM";
const both = "9:00 AM - 7:00 PM";


var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $("input:checked").length;
  $( "div" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
  
  if(n===2){
    $('#day').val(both);
  }  
  else if(($('#CheckMng').prop("checked") == true) && (n == 1)){
    $('#day').val(mng);  
  }
  else if(($('#CheckEve').prop("checked") == true) && (n == 1)){
    $('#day').val(eve);  
  }
  else
  {
    $('#day').val("");
  }   
};
countChecked();     
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" id="CheckMng">
    <input type="checkbox" id="CheckEve" >
    <div></div>
    <input type="text" id="day">
```

Comment: I am glad I was able to help! would you mind voting and accepting it as answer if you think it is worth?

Comment: My Reputation is less than 15  Sorry bro, Thanks fullll for your attention.  

Comment: @James you accepted the one which was not working?!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 issue:

1. You rely on clicking the label to trigger the function and check the tick box, if you do so, the function runs before the check box is clicked. Therefore when the user clicks the label, even though it was expected to be true, it was still false at the time the function is executed.
2. Clicking the checkbox does not trigger the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick event should be in the input tag like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="evening" name="working" onclick="shifting();"/>
```